# Visual Studio code task 2.0.0, move output to output

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup a typescript task in visual studio code Version 1.18.0 on a Mac. I am using the tasks.json version `2.0.0`. 
The task config looks like this:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "label": "Run typescript",
        "isBackground": true,
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc"
        ],
        "promptOnClose": false,
        "presentation": {
            "echo": false,
            "reveal": "never",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "dedicated"
        }
    }
]
```

}

The typescript task itself is working. However when I run the task it creates a new terminal section.

I would like the output of the tasks to use the OUTPUT window, illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: I think output is for program output, not typescript. Typescript uses terminal commands for compilation and watch.  Not sure why you want that.

Comment: All seed typescript projects I used, with tasks < 2, uses the output window?